# Is "Fear" used correctly here?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

In the following sentence

> "... I did not want to prolong his stay on the witness stand **for fear there** would not be any time left for them to call Darry Brewer that day."

1. Is the phrase construction in bold grammatically correct?
2. Is the usage common in this way?
3. Is there any other way *fear* could've been used in the sentence above?
4. Are any of the following usages correct?

   A) "... On the witness stand **because of the fear [that] there** would not be any time ..."

   B) "... On the witness stand **out of [the] fear [that] there** would not be any time..."

   C) "... On the witness stand **out of [the] fear of no time being left for them to call...**"

Comment: Why do you think it would not be correct?  You need to add more detail otherwise you're just asking us to check your grammar.

Comment: It's not my grammar! It's from a book by the name of Conviction: The untold story of putting Jodi Arias behind bars, by Juan Martinez.

Comment: Another option can be *I did not want to prolong his stay on the witness stand fearing that there would not be any time left for them to call Darry that day*.

Comment: @Bahram  Ok, then asking to check someone else's grammar.  The point is that you haven't really asked a question if I can answer with a simple "yes", or "no".  What do *you* think about this use of "fear"?  What makes you think that?  What else have you read or seen that makes you think it's right or wrong?  Details, please.

Comment: @Andrew I'd never seen "fear" used in this way before - in the sentence in the book. It's just not how I would construct a sentence using it. I wanted to make sure that it's not a typo in the book since I'd never seen or heard it used in this way anywhere else. I just checked the dictionary and there is an entry where "fear" is used in the same way as above. So, now I know it wasn't a typo.